# C - Storing values in array in a function

Tags: c, arrays, function

Question: Is there a way of storing (malloc/free) an array inside a function such that if I call the function multiple times in the main, it recalls the array generated the previous time I called it.

Details: I need to create a function with prototype:

```
double* Wee(int N)
```

which returns an array of size N.

The function is repeatedly called for different values of increasing N.
Suppose N = 4, then the array values are something like:

```
0.02 0.45 0.21 0.38
```

If N now equals 6, then the array values are:

```
0.02 0.45 0.21 0.38 0.56 0.81
```

Is there any way that I can get the function to remember the 4 values: 0.02 0.45 0.21 0.38 so that when I next call the function for N = 6, it doesn't need to calculate these again?

At the moment my N=6 array looks like this:

```
-6.27744e+066 -6.27744e+066 -6.27744e+066 -6.27744e+066 0.56 0.81
```

Comment: Read about [local `static` variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables).

Comment: Use realloc().  It does a lot of that for you.

Comment: @Jim Thank you Jim. I had already found my solution the static way, but I tried using realloc and have now learnt two things in one day. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered in the comments, but here is an implementation:

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

double * wee(int N);

int main(void)
{

    double * x;
    x = wee(4);
    //use x somehow;
    free(x);
    x = wee(6);
    //use x somehow;
    free(x);
    return 0;   
}

double * wee(int N)
{
    static int firstIn=1;
    int i;
    double *value;
    static double *previousValue;
    static int previousN = 0;

    srand(clock());

    value = malloc(sizeof(double)*N);

    //populate newly reallocated value with previousValues up to previousN
    for(i=0;i<previousN;i++)
    {
        value[i] = previousValue[i];    
    }

    //reallocate previousValue array to new size
    if(firstIn) 
    {
        previousValue = malloc(sizeof(double)*N);
        firstIn = 0;//do this only once
    }
    else
    {
        previousValue = realloc(previousValue, N);  
    }

    //now you are ready to put fresh numbers into newest elements of array
    for(i=previousN;i<N;i++)
    {
        value[i] = (double)rand();//populate only new array elements
        previousValue[i]=value[i];
    }
    previousN = N;


    return value;
}
```

***Note:*** freeing the double * previousValue could be accomplished by passing an additional argument such as double *wee(int N, BOOL cleanup);
Then you can pass 0 for N, and pass TRUE for your last call.  Write the function to bypass all code except the cleanup and return.

```
if(cleanup)
{
    free(previousValue);
}
```